# services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter(); error code: CS1061

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

Code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options => 
         options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

Error message:

```
Error   CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter' 
and no accessible extension method 'AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter' accepting a first argument of type 
'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   
AspCore_DB  C:\Startup.cs   30  Active
```

This code is officially introduced in the MS guide and I just followed. I'm working on MS Visual Studio 2019 v16.8.2.

Answer (score 119):

After doing some research I found that this is in the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore) library.

Comment: Sent a note to MS - credit to you @dennis https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/22482

Answer (score 2):

The `AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter` provides helpful error information in the development environment for EF migrations errors.

As outlined in the guide [Razor Pages with Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-the-database-exception-filter-1) in the section [Add the Database Exception Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-the-database-exception-filter-1) demonstrating how to implement `AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter` and `UseMigrationsEndPoint`…

To resolve this, add the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore) NuGet package.

In the Package Manager Console, enter the following to add the NuGet package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore
```

This NuGet package provides ASP.NET Core middleware for Entity Framework Core error pages. This middleware helps to detect and diagnose errors with Entity Framework Core migrations.

Answer (score 1):

guys you can install this package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.10 from -tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Package for Solution, this works for me.